# Do Not Display Specified Value From SQL Return In Asp.net WebForm GridView

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I have an `asp.net` application which has a `gridview` of all the users but i don't want the 'Admin' user to be displayed to the users.

**HTML**

```
<asp:GridView ID="tblUsers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlUsers" GridLines="None" Width="15%">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        </Columns>
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlUsers" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PaydayLunchConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] FROM [Users]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I have no code behind for this at all.  Will I need some sort of stored proc or something ad if so how would I write it as stored proc's are not my strong point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add just where cluase to your select command like SELECT [Name] FROM [Users] Where [name] != 'Admin' OR SELECT [Name] FROM [Users] Where [fieldname] != 'Admin'. see below code.

```
<asp:GridView ID="tblUsers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlUsers" GridLines="None" Width="15%">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlUsers" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PaydayLunchConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] FROM [Users] Where [name] != 'Admin'"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Cant believe I forgot I had the `SelectCommand` otherwise I wouldn't have needed to raise the question

Answer (score 0):

Just append a where clause to your SelectCommand.

**HTML**

```
<asp:GridView ID="tblUsers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlUsers" GridLines="None" Width="15%">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        </Columns>
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource 
       ID="SqlUsers" 
       runat="server" 
       ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PaydayLunchConnectionString1 %>" 
       SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] FROM [Users] WHERE [name] <> 'Admin'"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```